# Is a simple quotient group of finite $G$ isomorphic to any nontrivial simple normal subgroup of $G$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is a simple quotient group of finite $G$ isomorphic to any nontrivial simple normal subgroup of $G$? And if so, why?

To give context, assume that $G$ has the following two composition series:

$1 = H\unlhd I$ $\unlhd G$

and $1 = A\unlhd B$ $\unlhd G$.

I want to show that $G/I$ is isomorphic to $B$ without assuming the J-H Theorem.

Comment: Quotients need not be isomorphic to subgroups. For example, $A_5$ is the quotient of $\textrm{SL}_2(5)$ obtained by factoring by the 2-element center, but $A_5$ is not embeddable in $\textrm{SL}_2(5)$. [Reason: it could only embed as a subgroup of index 2, and $\textrm{SL}_2(5)$ has no such subgroup since it is perfect.]

Comment: Easier example: Let $G=S_3$, $I=A_3$.